# What to do when the OP answers their own question in comments/edits to the question?

Tags: discussion

With the clean-up in progress, I've come across quite a few questions which have a comment by the OP on how they solved their question or they answer their question in an edit to the question. How do we handle this so that question doesn't remain unanswered (technically)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When encoutered with such a scenario, it was advised in the [Ubuntu Regulators chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/206/ubuntu-regulators) to add the comment as a community wiki answer or edit the question to separate the question and the answer and add the answer as a community wiki answer with a note prepended saying,

> According to a comment/edit made by the OP

[Link to live example](https://askubuntu.com/questions/108077/help-installing-ubuntu-11-10)

*Just a reminder of how to mark an answer as a community wiki:*

[image]

Comment: don't forget to flag it as well indicating that the flag is for a wiki answer and needs upvoting - wiki answers still need 2 votes to make the answer "answered".

Comment: @fossfreedom correction, Its one vote :D

Comment: ... excellent - even easier to close :)

Comment: Don't forget to flag the comment, it's now considered somewhat useless and outdated. :)